# Variables scope which are defined within a while block in stored procedures - SQl Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, variables, scope, declaration

I've come across a interesting scenario (at least for me) in a stored procedure. Would like to have experts opinion and thoughts on it.

```
DECLARE @loopcounter INT
SET @loopcounter=10

WHILE @loopcounter > 0
BEGIN
  DECLARE @insidevalue int

  IF (@loopcounter%2 = 0)
  SET @insidevalue = @loopcounter

  PRINT 'Value_' + CAST(@insidevalue AS NVARCHAR) + '_'

  SET @loopcounter = @loopcounter - 1
END
```

I was expecting this block will give the output as below

> ```
> Value_10_
>
> Value_ _
>
> Value_8_
>
> Value_ _
>
> Value_6_
>
> Value_ _
>
> Value_4_
>
> Value_ _
>
> Value_2_
>
> Value_ _
> ```

Instead I got output as below:

> Value_10_
>
> Value_10_
>
> Value_8_
>
> Value_8_
>
> Value_6_
>
> Value_6_
>
> Value_4_
>
> Value_4_
>
> Value_2_
>
> Value_2_

I thought if I declare a variable inside a while block, then for every iteration it will reset the value to NULL or default value (from c# background).

If this is by design then my question is how does SQLServer treat 'DECLARE' statement for that variable inside while block? Does it ignore it as the variable is already in memory?

Can somebody please explain me this behavior?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The variable scope is the whole batch in this case a stored procedure.

It isn't re-declared every loop

So this is exactly as expected

Edit:

There is a recent [blog article](http://shaunjstuart.com/archive/2011/05/local-variables-declared-repeatedly) which is quite similar. The author was quickly corrected :-)

Comment: You mean it ignores declare statement in the next iteration?

Comment: If you want to put it like that, yes. But it isn't ignored because it has no meaning. SQL doesn't have scope like you are expecting.

Comment: I make a habit out of manually resetting variables that I declare within T-SQL loops in order to prevent this sort of behavior. It is indeed strange if you're used to working in a language like C#.

Comment: @John: Even I'll make this habit from now onwards, I never cared about it earlier.

Answer (score 18):

From [Transact-SQL Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> The scope of a variable is the range of Transact-SQL statements that
>   can reference the variable. The scope of a variable lasts from the
>   point it is declared until the end of the batch or stored procedure in
>   which it is declared.

The `DECLARE` is not in itself an executable statement. The variable declarations are all [identified at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14963921) and the memory reserved for them in the execution context.

If you use the 2008+ Declare and Set syntax. The Set part of the statement **will** occur every loop iteration however.

```
DECLARE @loopcounter INT
SET @loopcounter=10

WHILE @loopcounter > 0
BEGIN
  DECLARE @insidevalue INT = NULL

  IF (@loopcounter%2 = 0)
  SET @insidevalue = @loopcounter

  PRINT 'Value_' + CAST(@insidevalue AS NVARCHAR) + '_'

  SET @loopcounter = @loopcounter - 1
END
```

Comment: Is that mean `@insidevalue` will be NULL for every start of the loop (ie. re-initialized to NULL)?

Answer (score 15):

Try this for fun

```
if 1 = 0
begin
  -- will never happen
  declare @xx int
end  
else  
begin
  set @xx = 1
end  
print @xx
```

Apparently the declare code does not have to be executed. Only be declared before it is used.

This don't work

```
if 1 = 0
begin
  -- will never happen
  set @xx = 1
end  
else  
begin
  declare @xx int
end  
print @xx
```

Comment: +1 Interesting, if its not 'executed' it also won't pick up an initialiser e.g. `declare @xx int = 999`

Answer (score 6):

From [Declare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx):

> The scope of a local variable is the batch in which it is declared.

There are no more "local" scoping rules in T-SQL. It also means that you can't declare the same variable name inside IF and ELSE blocks.

All Declare does is *declare* a variable. It has no relation to *assignment*. The value of any variable that has never been assigned to is `NULL`. But thereafter, the only way the variables value will become `NULL` again is through an explicit assignment.

If you need it to be `NULL` at the top of each loop iteration, therefore, you must explicitly assign it.

Answer (score 3):

In T-SQL a `WHILE..END` is not individually scoped, you can for example `SELECT @insidevalue` after the `WHILE`'s `END`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 DECLARE @loopcounter INT
 DECLARE @insidevalue int
   SET @loopcounter=10
       WHILE @loopcounter > 0
        BEGIN
          IF (@loopcounter%2 = 0)
          BEGIN
          SET @insidevalue = @loopcounter
          PRINT 'Value_' + CAST(@insidevalue AS NVARCHAR) + '_'
          END
    ELSE
      PRINT 'Value_'+' '+'_'
      SET @loopcounter = @loopcounter - 1
   END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @loopcounter INT
SET @loopcounter=10

WHILE @loopcounter > 0
BEGIN
  DECLARE @insidevalue int
  IF (@loopcounter%2 = 0)
  begin

    set @insidevalue=@loopcounter
    PRINT 'Value_' + CAST(@insidevalue AS NVARCHAR) + '_'
  end
  ELSE

    PRINT 'Value_' + ' ' + '_'
    SET @loopcounter = @loopcounter - 1
END
```

Comment: It will be more understandable and looking goood if you can give a bit of description and do the code formatting evenly

Comment: This is just a copy from another answer with 0 explaination

Answer (score 0):

Integer data types often don't have NULL's only 0's

Declare statement won't happen each time within the loop

why don't you just use

```
DECLARE @loopcounter INT
SET @loopcounter=10
WHILE @loopcounter > 0
BEGIN
  IF @loopcounter%2 = 0
  PRINT 'Value_' + CAST(@loopcounter AS NVARCHAR) + '_'
  else
  PRINT 'Value_ _'
  SET @loopcounter = @loopcounter - 1
END
```

That gives:

```
Value_10_
Value_ _
Value_8_
Value_ _
Value_6_
Value_ _
Value_4_
Value_ _
Value_2_
Value_ _
```