# SQL server variable : loop vs duplicate?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Why **can** I declare the same variable name in a loop but **not** allowed without a loop ?

```
DECLARE @loop INT

SET @loop = 0

WHILE @loop<5
BEGIN
    DECLARE @t INT  -- <-- This is called multiple times
    SET @t = 1
    SET @loop = @loop+1
    SELECT @loop
END
```

- This will execute : 1,2,3,4,5

while this :

```
  DECLARE @t INT
  SET @t = 1
  DECLARE @t INT
  SET @t = 1
```

will obviously say :

- *The variable name '@t' has already been declared.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The placing of the `DECLARE` is immaterial (except the parser won't allow you to try and use it before the `DECLARE`)

It only actually declares one variable irrespective of how many times the block of code containing the declaration is executed.

The `DECLARE` is not in itself an executable statement. e.g.

```
IF 1 = 0
BEGIN
DECLARE @I INT
END

SELECT @I
```

Works fine even though that block is never entered. The memory for the variables is reserved at compilation time before execution of the query even begins in the [execution context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2007/01/09/1-0-structure-of-the-plan-cache-and-types-of-cached-objects.aspx).

One way of seeing this is

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;

GO

SELECT  m2.pages_allocated_count
        --If 2012 use the next line instead
        --,m2.pages_in_bytes/m2.page_size_in_bytes as pages_allocated_count
        ,m2.page_size_in_bytes
FROM   sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
       CROSS apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) t
       JOIN sys.dm_os_memory_objects m1 ON m1.memory_object_address = cp.memory_object_address
       JOIN sys.dm_os_memory_objects m2 ON m1.page_allocator_address = m2.page_allocator_address
WHERE  text LIKE '%this query%'
 AND m2.type = 'MEMOBJ_EXECUTE'

DECLARE @A0 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @A1 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @A2 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @A3 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @A4 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @A5 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @A6 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @A7 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @A8 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @A9 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @A10 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @A11 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @A12 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @A13 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @A14 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @A15 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @A16 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @A17 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @A18 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @A19 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @A20 VARCHAR(8000);
```

which shows memory reserved for the current query, if you adjust the number of variables declared you will see the memory reserved change even though the `DECLARE` block is right at the end of the batch.

Comment: in while loop it will declare the variable `@t` 5 times ?

Comment: @vikas - No. The `DECLARE` statements do nothing at run time. In the same way that in the example code in my answer the block is executed 0 times but the variable is still actually declared.

Comment: like variable declaration inside for loop in C#, or something else

Comment: @vikas in c# it's a block scope.

Comment: @MartinSmith so you're basically say that becuase of compile time checking - there is an error. while in runtime - there is no problem ...right ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Not sure what you are asking. All variables declared in a batch are in the same scope and the parser doesn't allow you to have two different variables named with the same identifier. That would obviously a bad idea and is true in all programming languages AFAIK. If you are asking about why you can't do `SELECT @I;DECLARE @I INT` then I presume the parser is probably a single pass parser.